# Should I use spacing between boards on a chunky oak table?

Tags: wood, tabletop, hardwood

I am building a solid oak (dried) table of 4 boards of 180 x 20 x 5 cm. This will stay in my home office in UK so temperature ranging between 18-28 degrees and humidity 40-60%.

This is going to be a rustic / character table and I am not sure what kind of vertical and horizontal expansion-shrinking to expect. I need go know if I should include some space between planks and also if using screws to fix the tabletop on the metal frame (3 beams) would not risk cracking the wood. How deep should the screws go down? With 5cm thickness I would assume about 3.5mm-4mm should be ok with pilot drilled holes.

I think I would probably not mind having even 4-5mm gaps as long I can keep table to planned. 
Potential curbing worries me the most.

US “translation”: 180 cm is about 6 feet, 5cm is a bit less than 2 inches, 20 cm is 7.8 in inches.[image: solid oak baords for tabletop]

Comment: I presume you specifically want separate boards? Simpler in many ways to make a single panel, but if you can't or don't want to then don't worry. Re. the movement you can expect to see, this is dependent on the cut of each board as much as known humidity variations — quarter-sawn wood can expand appox. half as much as flat-sawn.

Comment: *"How deep should the screws go down?"* Were you planning on screwing through the boards into a frame below?

Comment: What is the purpose of the screws?  To hold the table down, or to stop side-to-side movement?  Personally  I would want to have the screw thread into the wood longer than the piece it holds.

Comment: Screws would have two roles: first to tension the boards a little bit in order to keep them on the same plane (now there is small twist of 2-3mm but with 3 screws per board it should make it stay in desired position as i found that 30-40kg force was enough to straiten them. Second role of the screws is to control the distance between boards. My plan is to not glue the boards and to keep about 2-3mm between them, and to round the boards a little to avoid any splintering.

Comment: Main reason for gaps: i want to avoid a lot of planning using my handheld planner as I am afraid I would fail to make them fit perfectly. Also by having each board separated I would make the table easy to dismantle for moving (otherwise it would be impossible to ever move it outside my small home office room). Worth mentioning that this is not a dinner table, is going to be my office table, replacing the MDF panel that I currently have... and hate. Regarding finishing probably only beeswaxing. I still wonder what grit size should be the last one to use.

Comment: *"Second role of the screws is to control the distance between boards"* You can't really control this, and actually you shouldn't try. The boards should be left free to expand and contract (which is what the gaps you intent to leave are for anyway). If you could prevent the boards from moving with really heavy fixings the wood will try to relieve the internal stresses generated by other means, including cupping or splitting. Attach them to the framing from below, one stout screw each end of the boards should be fine, and then they can expand and contract outwards from their centres.